# Is $S_t = \max_{0\leq s\leq t} B_s$ a continuous semimartingale?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, brownian-motion, martingales

I'm trying to apply Itô Formula to $F(B_t,S_t) = (S_t-B_t)^2$ where $S_t = \max_{0\leq s\leq t} B_s$, but first I need to know if $S_t$ is a continuous semimartingale. I know that $B_t$ is, since $B_t^2-t$ is a martingale and $B_t = B_t + 0$ being $0$ of bounded variation. However, is the maximum of a continuous semimartingale a semimartingale itself?

Any help, any hint is welcome. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hmm, maybe you overlooked that fact that $S$ by itself is an increasing continuous adapted process

Comment: I had it in mind but... does it imply something? Thank you!

Comment: An increasing function has bounded variation, therefore $S_t = 0+S_t$ is a semimartingale and its "local martingale part" is $0$.

Comment: True. Thank you!